# ASP.Net MVC how to display linq query data to an string array in view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have an application I want to add tags input box

I used http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html  library

Controller Create Method:

```
        // GET: Posts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var Tags = db.MyTags.Select(t=>t.TagName).ToArray();

        ViewBag.ExistingTags = Tags;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

I have below script

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'go', 'lua'];
        var sampleTags = JSON.stringify(@ViewBag.ExistingTags);

</script>
```

how can I get the passed ExistingTags array as the sample code commented

Comment: Stephen you are incorrect reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()` and `Json.Encode()` as shown :-

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'go', 'lua'];
        var sampleTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ExistingTags));
</script>
```

Comment: @MehdiJalal..happy to help you..;)